# Liquibase Execution order when the changelog has includeAll instead of include one xml

Tags: liquibase

In the master change log, we use multiple includeAll to point to folder locations that have multiple changesets

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
<includeAll path="liquibase/00.02" />
<includeAll path="liquibase/00.04" />
<includeAll path="iquibase/00.05" />
<includeAll path="liquibase/00.06" />
<includeAll path="liquibase/00.07" /> </databaseChangeLog>
```

and within each folder we have multips changelogs with sql operations.
For example in **liquibase/007** folder we have changelog1, changelog2 and changelog3

What would be the execution order of the changelog xmls within that folder?

Answer (score 0):

We had trouble with controlling order until we standardized on a clearly readable feature file format. Ours is

`yyyymmdd-app-ticketNo.xml` or `yyyymmdd-app-ticketNo.sql`

Example: `20200328-LD-42.xml`

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/includeall.html